# Bootstrap collapse hiding navigation links on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project using the bootstrap and in starting the fixed navigation on top I have found that it is hiding the links (ie. Home, Account, Logoff), presumably collapsing them. Because when i shrink it down and get the toggle it will display them after i initiate it.  When I remove the .collapse from just below the first comment it displays the links. However then it will not collapse on resizing. How do I get the top nav links to show and still have the toggle work? Note: All of the file paths to the css and js are correct directories

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
  <head>
    <title>project</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
       <!-- Problem is here -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your markup works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/pJGSw/embedded/result/, have you added any js code to your page that may be causing the navbar to collapse on page load?

Comment: That is really strange. No, I've literally just been trying to get the structure down before I go in and make any customization. Everything is straight from the bootstrap files.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because I was trying to combine js and css from both Bootstrap 2 and 3. Once I got everything on the same playing field it works just fine.